# Looping audio and inputdialog box cancel

Tags: java

Im trying to get a backtrack on my JOptionPane game working. I have the code for the audio to loop. But when a user clicks cancel on an inputdialog box it exits the game but does not close the audio thread.
I need something to kill the audio thread when this happens.

I have tried other methods of playing the audio .wav file. But when user hit cancel it still plays. Have tried using JFrames and disposing of the frame, but this doesn't dispose the audio thread too.

```
URL urlfog = theFog.class.getClassLoader().getResource("thefog.wav");
AudioInputStream audioStreamfog = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(urlfog);
AudioFormat formatfog = audioStreamfog.getFormat();
DataLine.Info infofog = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, formatfog);
Clip audioClipfog = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(infofog);
audioClipfog.open(audioStreamfog);
audioClipfog.loop(audioClipfog.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);


String name;

do {
    name = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Hello what is your name?","The Fog",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon1,null,"");
}
while (name.equalsIgnoreCase(""));
```

No error messages just the audio is still playing after a cancel of the program.

Comment: `audioClipfog.stop()` DId you try this in your cancel?

Comment: What was this method?

Comment: yes the method of `audioClipfog` as Clip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String name;
do {
    name = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Hello what is your name?", "The Fog", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon1, null, "");

    if ((name == null)) {
        audioClipfog.stop();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
while (name.equalsIgnoreCase(""));
```